# How to provide correctly a tuple parameter to pyDocumentDB query

Tags: python-2.7, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I tried in many ways to send a tuple parameter like:
`{"name": "@p", "value": tuple(['a','b']) }`

to the query, which is simple as:

`select * from c where c.p in @p`

I always get a syntax error or no results.
when i'm copying the parameter from the console to a query i get the results as expected.

help?

Answer (score 1):

According to the section [`Request Body`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/querying-documentdb-resources-using-the-rest-api#request-body) of the REST reference `Querying DocumentDB resources using the REST API`, the requirement for the value of the parameter as below.

> parameters Required. A JSON array of parameters specified as name value pairs. The parameter array can contain from zero to many parameters.Each parameter must have the following values:name: the name of the parameter. Parameter names must be valid string literals and begin with ‘@’. **value: the value of the parameter. Can be any valid JSON value (string, number, object, array, Boolean or null).**

So you can pass a Python tuple parameter for a DocumentDb query, please using an array like `['a', 'b']` instead of `tuple(['a', 'b'])`, or just convert it via the code like `list(tuple(['a', 'b']))`.

---

**Update:**

I reviewed the source code of `pydocumentdb` and found the `parameters` in the request body of the DocumentDb query is serialized by using the method `json.wraps` which will serialize the `tuple` to `list`. For example, execute the code `json.wraps(('a', 'b'))`, then get the result `['a', 'b']`. So if using `pydocumentdb`, the only way for your case is that directly embed the tuple value into the query string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Peter, I tried using an array. but it does not seems to work. 
I used tuple just to get the form of `where c.p IN ('a,'b','c')`. 
To which form is the array being translated to?

Comment: @Amitbe Unfortunately, I tried to solve the issue, but failed because of the content I updated on my post above.